# How can I set up Windows Server to wake on LAN?

Tags: windows-server-2012, wake-on-lan

I have been trying to set up wake on LAN for a little while now, but I can never get it to work.

I want to be able to wake the computer over the internet. I have already set up ports 7 and 9 to forward to my computer on my router, and I know the computer receives the signal because I have tried applications that detect an incoming magic packet. I have also set up the BIOS to wake on network, and enabled all wake on LAN (wol) options in the network adapter from the device manager. Also, I have disabled all efficiency (eco) options in the BIOS and OS.

However I still cannot get the computer to wake on LAN.

My computer is custom built with a MSI 970A-G46 motherboard and runs Windows Server 2012 Datacenter R2 x64.

I would greatly appreciate ideas on how to make this work.

Comment: Does it work within your LAN? Are you sure you have the right ports forwarded for your mainboard? I believe they are UDP port numbers... lastly: a server should never be allowed to go to any state other than on or shutdown...

Comment: Firstly as Big Chris says you have to test it locally to know for sure what is going on. However couple of bits to keep in mind. Bios settings will only affect on-board NIC's for PCI/PCI-E NIC's you need to configure it on the card. also what WOL you using because from memory the ports for what I've used are: mc-wol.exe uses UDP port 65535. AMD's Magic Packet Utility uses UDP port 2304. Linux tool named wakeonlan uses UDP port 9 (albeit there is a Windows version to uses Port 9 also).